# Raspberry pi on Qt 5.1.1: Remote path not set

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

I try to run my project on Raspberry Pi. Using the instructions at:

http://qt-project.org/wiki/RaspberryPi_Beginners_guide

I have set up a kit for the Raspberry with the proper Qt version, compiler and debugger.
I am however not able to run my project as the “play” button is greyed out with the message “Don’t know what to run”. When I look under the “Run” tab in the “Build & Run” option it says “Remote path not set” as shown in the screen dump below. How do I set this????

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found out that I needed to add the following to each .pro file which are needed:
target.path = /home/pi/path/to/my/executable
INSTALLS += target

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

(Under the line TARGET = [name of target executable])

> target.files = [name of target executable]
>   target.path = [remote device path i.e. /home/user]
>   INSTALLS = target

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes changes in *.pro files won't take effect until Qt Creator is restarted. Maybe this is the case.