# Deployment not working and executable extension

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I use Qt Creator 2.8.1 on Windows, no deployment menu (configure) available.
Cross compile for ARM target device.

I defined toolchain which is ok except GDB, cross compiler and kit (all together).
The application is built either in debug and release mode but two things I need more:

- executable name is always *.exe. This is a linux ARM binary, cannot change this?
- deploy not available at all (neither run menu)

I must scp by hand, change attributes and run. Can be automatic little bit?
However, I can create a batch file witch pscp but isn't suppose Qt Creator handle this?

Comment: Out of curiosity: which toolchain are you using? Also, which embedded platorm is this?

Comment: quick question why 2.8.1.?

Comment: because 3.0 is not working properly on XP, the property menus are collapsing one over each other and it's much slower

Comment: @dan: even if it was working on XP, using the newest is not always necessary just because there is a newer version available, especially if it is a new major release. :)

Comment: agree :) these days.. newest, worse, more cpu, more ram, more GB... My XP it's absolute rocket.. I would not change for anything right now.

Comment: ty :) was just wondering the reason why you're exactly using 2.8.1 :) happy new year everyone

Answer (score 2):

It is only the matter of proper toolchain and deployment setup. Here you can find the screenshots of mine from my QtCreator session where you can customize the kit and deployment as you wish.

Please make sure you have the right "-spec" argument there because that will determine the toolchain used, and it is important to be set up properly.

As for the deployment, you can put the commands in there that you would otherwise put into your Windows batch file, et al.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Laszlo, I don't have "deploy  locally" just "deploy to remote linux host". And there is a yellow icon that says "don't know what to run"

Comment: @user1973900: yes, that is expected since you are trying to deploy to a remote target as opposed to locally. Yet, the customization is very similar. The warning is probably due to the fact it cannot figure out for you automatically, hence the customization. There can be so many different deploying steps, so just specify and chain the commands as you wish.

Comment: Do I have to enable some FTP on target? rignt now it's only SCP and working well.. even Qt can read the processes, environment, etc. ?
PS. It's my own built SDK :) hope I'm not missing something :)

Comment: @user1973900: Why do you need an ftp server on the target for scp on the host? You would need that or sftp, but not for scp. I used to see custom SDKs, like with Yocto, but it should work in general. You can always give a try to the official SDK to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I read some posts on net about SFPT (sorry, spell). Ok, I'll see what to do.. at mine, I have no files at all in Deployment -> Files to deploy.. perhaps here is the problem. Ok, thanks and happy new year.

Comment: @user1973900: no, that is not a problem. You can use your command to deploy it, and you can also use deployment/installation statements in qmake. Happy New Year, you, too!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem here, thanks stackoverflow:

[Raspberry pi on Qt 5.1.1: Remote path not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146264/raspberry-pi-on-qt-5-1-1-remote-path-not-set)

In the project .pro file must be set the remote path for deploying:

target.path = /root/john/qt
INSTALLS += target

And now, the deployment works as expected.

There is one problem more... on my XP, executable is with .exe extension. In the same project .pro file, must change:

TARGET = untitled1.exe

If anyone knows how to get ride of .exe extension, appreciate.

Thanks all for suggestions,

Comment: This is not a forum site, hence the posts are not rolling. There should be one question, and the rest is about answer(s). Please modify your post respectively. Also, it is weird that you post an answer without answering the questions first. It feels like a bit write-only. :)

Comment: OT: this looks really strange: `target.path = /root/john/qt`